# Print key if any nested value matches a set value

Tags: json, jq

This is best explained with expected input and output.

Given this input:

```
{
  "27852380038": {
    "compute_id": 34234234,
    "to_compute": [
      {
        "asset_id": 304221854,
        "new_scheme": "mynewscheme",
        "original_host": "oldscheme1234.location.com"
      },
      {
        "asset_id": 12123121,
        "new_scheme": "myotherscheme",
        "original_host": "olderscheme1234.location.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  "31352333022": {
    "compute_id": 43888877,
    "to_compute": [
      {
        "asset_id": 404221555,
        "new_scheme": "mynewscheme",
        "original_host": "oldscheme1234.location.com"
      },
      {
        "asset_id": 52123444,
        "new_scheme": "myotherscheme",
        "original_host": "olderscheme1234.location.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And the `asset_id` that I'm searching for, 12123121, the output should be:

```
27852380038
```

So I want the top level keys where any of the `asset_id`s in `to_compute` match my input `asset_id`.

I haven't seen any jq example so far that combines nested access with an any test / if else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task can be accomplished without using environment variables, e.g.

```
< input.json jq -r --argjson ASSET_ID 12123121 '
  to_entries[]
  | {key, asset_id: .value.to_compute[].asset_id}
  | select(.asset_id==$ASSET_ID)
  | .key'
```

or more efficiently, using the filter:

```
to_entries[]
| select( any( .value.to_compute[]; .asset_id==$ASSET_ID) )
| .key
```

Answer (score 1):

With some help from a coworker I was able to figure it out:

```
$ export ASSET_ID=12123121
$ cat input.json | jq -r "to_entries[] | .value.to_compute[] + {job: .key} | select(.asset_id==$ASSET_ID) | .job"
27852380038
```

Comment: This kind of string interpolation is generally not a good idea (that is, it only works in special cases).  One of several good alternatives is to use `env.ASSET_ID` instead.  Consider also using a command-line option, e.g. `--argjson ASSET_ID "$ASSET_ID"`